# How to set the size of a cell in a MathTable Manim

Tags: manim

I have a MathTable in Manim

```py
import * from manim


class Scene(Scene):
    def construct(self):

        # ...

        quarks = MathTable([
            ["u", "c", "t"],
            ["d", "s", "b"],
            include_outer_lines = True
        ])

        self.play(Create(quarks))
```

How can I set the size of all cells, to, let's say, (2, 1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an `h_buff` which is divided by two and applied as horizontal padding at left and right inside each cell:

```py
class Test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        quarks = MathTable([
            ["u", "c", "t"],
            ["d", "s", "b"],
            ],
            h_buff=2,
            include_outer_lines = True
        )
        self.play(Create(quarks))
        self.wait()
```

[image: Result]